# My components are compressing when i use the keyboard

Tags: react-native, expo

My problem is when i use the keyboard, all of my components are compressed and i want to know why this is happend and what can i do to prevent this happening?

Here is my code 
i use image_height export

@react-native-community/masked-view": 0.1.6
    expo: ^37.0.0
    react: 16.9.0
    react-dom": "16.9.0

```
render() {
    return (

        <Animated.View style={styles.container}
            behavior={Platform.OS == "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}>
            {/* <View style={styles.statusBar} /> */}
            <View style={{ height: '12%' }}></View>
            <View style={styles.content}>

                <Text style={styles.title}>asdada</Text>

                <View style={[styles.inputContainer, { marginTop: "15%" }]}>
                    {/* <Image style={styles.inputIcon} source={require('./Imagenes/mail_login.png')}/> */}
                    <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
                        placeholder="Correo"
                        placeholderTextColor="#848484"
                        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
                        onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })} />
                </View>
                <View style={{ height: '70%', width: '100%', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', marginTop: '10%' }}>
                    <TouchableHighlight style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]} onPress={() => this.login()}>
                        <Text style={styles.loginText}>Ingresar</Text>
                    </TouchableHighlight>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Animated.View >
    );
}
}
```

in the styles i use width and height with %, for example width: '10%

[image: This is without keyboard]

[image: And this is with the keyboard]

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any prop of `View` named `behavior`, You should use `keyboardavoidingview` for this

https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview.

Or you can use this one too.

https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view